# Yammer localhost:4200 authentication and CORS issue

Tags: yammer

We are trying to get yammer to authenticate us so that we can call the API's

We failing at CORS in chrome

Error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?clientid=CKZizu8QZi2j3Vxc1P…secret=ZALshkEpgdJKdtzeR1zNagbSAE4GZF4hgMasQJUQ&code=aiCrJsB2VT2ZmIwUbjFOw. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I have added localhost:4200 in the Origins for my App but not sure what other configuration is required as we cant get this working.

How can I find out what is needed to be configured for localhost:4200 to work?

Comment: Search for "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" on the internet. I'm guessing you'll find the answer. Also read the links in the Related section to the right.

Comment: Also, you've now shared your "secret" key to the world...

Comment: Thanks Mike. I am working on Angular2 with Lite Server do you know how i can rectify this?

Comment: @SaeedAnsari have you find the solution?